# mouse pointer moves too fast

Tags: drivers, mouse

the mouse settings are already set to "accellaration" - "slow" and "Sensitivity" "Low" and the mouse pointer moves fast. Any fixes for this. I'm using a Gigabyte Bluetooth mouse, Unity 11.10.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: This may be what you need: https://askubuntu.com/questions/135122/reduce-the-mouse-sensitivity