# Fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 install mouse too fast

Tags: mouse

The mouse is too fast however in settings I cannot reduce the mouse speed at all, as it is already all the way to the left.  I've had this problem with this computer forever and it's a real nuisance.  Probably need to report it as a bug?

Comment: I've had success with the 'xinput' section of this article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration

Comment: Do you have an ultra-high resolution gaming mouse? My Steel Series mouse has a button which toggles between two modes. If I have the mouse in one mode the pointer moves way too fast; but if I hit the button to switch to the other mode, it moves at normal speed.

Comment: It's a razer naga hex, no way to switch it on the mouse that I know of

Comment: I encourage you to make a bug report as soon as possible and post the link here. Maybe the bug will be fixed in time for Utopic Unicorn. It will never get fixed if you don't report it. However, what package would this be filed against? My best guess is X or Linux.

Comment: Not sure I doubt it would get fixed in time for next release anyway, I submitted one about a month ago and they haven't really looked at it yet

Comment: I reported it as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1379878

Comment: Daniel, what kind of mouse do you have? USB, or wireless? Does it have drivers for Linux? If so, are they installed? If they are, are they completely updated?

Comment: try `xset m 1 1` http://askubuntu.com/questions/135122/reduce-the-mouse-sensitivity/745584#745584

Answer (score 0):

The real cure is I have a 2008 Compaq desktop with Windows 7 on 1 hard drive and Ubuntu 16.04 on another. When I first installed Ubuntu the mouse was so fast Even moving the mouse speed slider all the way to slow did not help.
After searching out the fix I got all this info. First open the terminal, and type
`xinput --list --short`. This brings up virtual core pointer. In the top section will see your mouses name (mine is YESTEK G Mouse) id=8 write down your mouses id # only (8) save ! now in terminal, type `xinput --list-props 8` your mouses id #. push enter and look for Device Accel Constant Deceleration write # behind your mouse id # mine was (270) so 8 270  then behind those you need a # from 2 to 8 (lower # faster movement Higher # slower movement) Now in terminal type `xinput --set-prop 8 270 6` push enter this will slow your mouse way down if to slow re-enter `xinput --set-prop 8 270 5` keep changing last # till you like the speed and you can use system setting, mouse & Touchpad speed slider for fine tuning speed. Hope this helps!

These settings will only stay till you restart so keep them wrote down if you know how to save them to start-up Find the Startup Applications Preferences app Open it then save the settings you like by clicking add on the right and on the small form give your settings a name I used mouse speed, in command type `xinput --set-prop 8 270 6` click the add button on small form. 
Next startup thell be working at startup.