# Locate the id of input device and change the value of its property

Tags: bash, mouse, scripts

I learned from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135122/reduce-the-mouse-sensitivity) that you can set mouse speed by the following:

```
$ xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4
```

where `10` is the `id` of the target device, which you can obtain by checking the output of `xinput` command.

However, I problem is that every time I unplug my mouse and re-plug it, its `id` changes. Thus simply putting the line above into a `mouse.sh` isn't sufficient. I need also to dynamically search for the current `id` value of the target device, i.e., my mouse.

The tragic part is that I know nothing at all about bash script, and thus here to seek for a quick fix for my specific problem:

> How to write this simple script to locate the `id` of an input device, say `mouse`, and use this `id` in the `xinput` line above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `xinput` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xinput.1.html):

> device can be the **device name** as a string or the XID of the device.

It means that you can just give the full name of your mouse to the `xinput` command.

Let's first identify your mouse device, type `xinput` in a terminal:

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Logitech Illuminated Keyboard    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Pure Optical           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Pro Webcam C920                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech Illuminated Keyboard    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Pure Optical           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ No brand 2Port KVMSwicther                id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here my mouse is a `ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Pure Optical` but you can't use it as is because this type of mouse declares several devices (a gaming mouse).

So prefix the device name with 'pointer:' as follow:

```
$ xinput --set-prop 'pointer:ROCCAT ROCCAT Kone Pure Optical' "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4
```

Adjust the above command to match your own device and you can paste it in your `mouse.sh` script.

Comment: That's really convenient. Thanks for the nice solution. Especially for the `pointer:` part.