# Locate the id of multiple input devices and change the value of its property

Tags: 14.04, bash, mouse, upstart, xinput

I was looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572726/locate-the-id-of-input-device-and-change-the-value-of-its-property) which answers if there is only one of the device names. The id's can change when unplugging the device and plugging it back in, this is why I need to get them by their names. I however have two:

[image]

```
SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse
```

How would I fix this in a script? I need the first one to have specific settings and the second one to have specific settings.

In other words how do I acquire both id's and in the order they appear? Some sort of for loop that checks the output or something.

Comment: You can distinguish them by their id #.

Comment: Run `xinput | grep "id=12"` to get the first one, and `xinput | grep "id=14"` to get the second one, assuming that those id's don't change.

Comment: @Daniel If you follow the link to the other question you shall see it states that the id may change.

Comment: @Ron Updated my question.

Comment: Are there indeed 2 different devices or is one a wifi-adapter?

Comment: @Ron My mouse a `sensei raw` has a button which switches settings for the mouse (hence the two SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse pointers). Nothing to do with WiFi. It's a wired gaming mouse (not wireless).

Answer (score 0):

Someone in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755967/how-to-make-a-program-that-finds-ids-of-xinput-devices-and-sets-xinput-some-set/18756948#18756948) has provided a nice script that might help you. Change the commands accordingly.

You can do something like the following:

> ```
> if [ "$SEARCH" = "" ]; then 
>     exit 1
> fi
>
> ids=$(xinput --list | awk -v search="$SEARCH" \
>     '$0 ~ search {match($0, /id=[0-9]+/);\
>                   if (RSTART) \
>                     print substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3)\
>                  }'\
>      )
>
> for i in $ids
> do
>     xinput set-prop $i 'Device Accel Profile' -1
>     xinput set-prop $i 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
>     xinput set-prop $i 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1.0
> done
> ```

So with this you first find all the IDs which match the search pattern
`$SEARCH` and store them in `$ids`. Then you loop over the IDs and
execute the three `xinput` commands.

You should make sure that `$SEARCH` does not match to much, since this
could result in undesired behavior.

Comment: Very nice, will try it.