# I'm missing mouse pointer speed option in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse-pointer

I have a wireless mouse and I cannot change my pointer speed...I don't have the option in the mouse menu. Only for touch-pad.

P.S. Newbie here...

Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue. There is a temporary solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135122/reduce-the-mouse-sensitivity).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I found an easier way...I plugged in a wire mouse and the option appeared. Changed it to my desired speed, put the wireless mouse in, problem solved. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your comment. Actually I found an easier way...I plugged in a wire mouse and the option appeared. Changed it to my desired speed, put the wireless mouse in, problem solved. :) –

Answer (score 4):

For me, I'm using a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000, and no workarounds were working. lxinput and xset both did nothing, however I did manage to get xinput to work.

I got the id of my mouse from here:

```
$> xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  

pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)] <- I picked this one
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Webcam C615                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple, Inc Apple Keyboard                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple, Inc Apple Keyboard                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I picked 13, since there were multiple id's with the same name, and listed the properties:

```
$> xinput list-props 13
Device 'Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Product ID (269):    1118, 1861
    Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (285): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (287):  0
    Axis Labels (288):  "Rel X" (162), "Rel Y" (163), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (277), "Rel Dial" (278), "Rel Vert Wheel" (279), "Rel Misc" (280)
    Button Labels (289):    "Button Left" (155), "Button Middle" (156), "Button Right" (157), "Button Wheel Up" (158), "Button Wheel Down" (159), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (160), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (161), "Button Side" (275), "Button Extra" (276), "Button Unknown" (273), "Button Unknown" (273), "Button Unknown" (273), "Button Unknown" (273)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (290): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (291):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (292):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (293): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (294): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (295):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (296):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (297):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (298):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (299):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (300):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (301): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (302):  0
```

Notice how there is no mention of "Mouse Acceleration" or any such thing. I suspected that "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" had something to do with speed, so I tried changing the values:

```
&> xinput --set-prop 13 "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.300000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.300000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

It worked! I just multiplied the first 2 "1.0000000"'s by the same number (which I guess are X and Y speed) and now my mouse has a good speed.

Answer (score 3):

The code above is a good one and probably will fix for most users however for the sake of documentation i want to share further:

Lubuntu, Ubuntu, Xubuntu lxinput, xinput mouse decelaration missing, no speed control, no acceleration control, only mouse pad working etc... This code is the cure of all problems.

For lubuntu users first

```
sudo apt-get install xinput
```

then for all users

```
xinput --list
```

obtain your device id and then

```
xinput set-prop ID-HERE "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" HERE, 0, 0, 0, HERE, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Here is full command which i do not fully understand:

```
id="pointer:Neo Reflection Neo Reflection Finger Mouse"; speed=0.333; xinput set-prop ID-HERE "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" HERE, 0, 0, 0, HERE, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

You can use either of these commands they both work fine for me.ID-HERE will be your device id number most likely 10 to 15 though it may differ don't panic.

HERE will be speed x and y so make sure they are the same. Start out with 0.2 , i'm using 0.4 but i like it slow so it may differ for you. This line of code is a life saver and works in every situation.

You need to add it to startup, it,s gone once you restart. Note that xinput only works after X session starts, which means you have to execute it after logging in.

Here is how i did it on my lubuntu:

Create a script.sh file in somewhere isolated:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
xinput set-prop ID-HERE "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" HERE, 0, 0, 0, HERE, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Create the file /home/USERNAME/.config/autostart/mouse.desktop :
Edit and paste:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Mouse
Comment=Mouse sensitivity fix
Exec=sh /PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

Now this app can be seen in your Default applications for Lxsession => Autostart tab.

Hope this helps someone since mouse problems with lubuntu is very common.

Edit: [Source for code](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149147)