# Adjusting mouse Sensitivity/DPI in Ubuntu

Tags: mouse

I'm very new to the linux environment, I've just installed Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10 today, everything works perfectly, except that my mouse sensitivity is way higher than in Windows 10.

I have a Logitech Gaming Mouse G302, I've set the slider all the way down in the System Settings, and I've used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135122/reduce-the-mouse-sensitivity) guide to try to adjust it and I've made it somewhat usable but still not comfortable. In Windows my setting are 800 DPI and 6/11 ticks, with Mouse Acceleration turned off, is there any way to replicate these exact settings in Ubuntu?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you changed the `DPI Cycle` button on the mouse itself?

Comment: No I haven't, I don't even have other DPI options in the mouse memory, I just set it to 800 DPI and unmapped the using the Logitech Gaming software.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Logitech Gaming Software, but can you define multiple DPI settings and load that into the mouse, and then use the DPI Cycle button to switch DPI on the fly? Try 300DPI.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but only on windows since the Software only works there, I'll load some settings on my mouse and see what works best, I actually have a hunch that my mouse speed on Ubuntu is 2x the mouse speed on windows, so probably 400 DPI will work, I'll post the results when I'm done.

Comment: 400 DPI did work, it feels exactly the same as 800 DPI in windows, I've now set that my mouse can cycle between 800 and 400 DPI, I never had use for it before but I suppose I have now, thanks for the help, is there any way I can close the question or mark it as answered? I'm new to StackExchange.

Comment: Let me put that into a quick answer that you can accept, ok? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

The Logitech Gaming Mouse G302 has a DPI Cycle button that allows the user to change the DPI setting of the mouse on the fly. This must be set using the Logitech Gaming Software for Windows. Once set, the DPI Cycle switch can be used in Ubuntu to select the desired mouse speed.